# SSH Tunnel channel open failed (SOCKS)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks

to bypass geographic filters using my laptop I connect via ssh to my home server.

I use this command:

```
ssh -D 8081 Me@myhomeserver.noip.net
```

I have convigured firefox proxy settings with localhost and 8081

When I open any web page, I get these errors, but the page is loaded

```
channel 26: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 32: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 26: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 26: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 27: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 26: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

On my server I set the sshd_config file with these settings

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
PermitTunnel yes
PermitOpen any
```

My server is under nat.

What is missing?

Comment: Loading any web page opens a lot of connections. Some of them  could not have been established (errors). This could be because of slow connection, inaccessible server of some sort etc. Using proxy over ssh you will see many of these types of errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879297/13317

Comment: @KrzysztofSawicki I think it's as you say, I tried with a faster connection and I did not encounter any particular problems.